# Pages included in another page and duplicate content issues for SEO

Tags: permalinks, page-template, seo, include

in a recent project I've decided to create a page template (PageX) which is a kind of "stack" of subpages. This template simply includes the content of three other separate pages (PageA, PageB, PageC).

I'm just trying now to find the best way to avoid duplicate content for SEO, as Wordpress automatically create specific permalinks for these 3 subpages.

Is there a way to tell Wordpress that these pages must not have permalinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [NOINDEX, FOLLOW meta robots tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) on the this 'stack' page, or the individual pages.

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

This lets search engines crawl the page and all links on it, but they will not index the page and so any content on it won't get counted as duplicate content.

The code goes within the `<head>` section of the pages source code. You can easily define the code using plugins such as [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) or [Ultimate Noindex Nofollow Tool II](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-noindex-nofollow-tool-ii/)

Comment: I think the idea is good and I've already implemented it but not on the 'stack page'. I think it's better to do that on each individual subpages.